# How to disable the ASUS VivoBook app?

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad

So recently I've bought an ASUS K551LN, the design is pretty cool and all, but they added a pointless key on the keyboard which opens up an app called ASUS VivoBook. The app basically lets you see how much storage you have left, your memory usage, your current Power4Gear power plan, ASUS Cloud, Touch Pad, ASUS Smart Gesture, Splendid, and Audio Wizard, of all which I think are useless.

When the app is started the first time since boot up, the notification would pop up saying "ASUS VivoBook is initializing, please wait..." and then few seconds later the app appears. This is extremely annoying as I would sometimes press it accidentally while typing or playing games. I couldn't find a way to disable this bloatware, other than uninstalling it, but I am afraid something bad might happen.

Another question: Seems like ASUS replaced the previous touch pad program with their new one, "ASUS Smart Gesture". In Windows 7, a tab in a browser (IE, Chrome, etc.) can be closed by two fingers tapping within the touch pad area, but the Smart Gesture replaced it with "Show pop-up menu" which acts the same way you would right-click anywhere. That is pretty annoying too as I have to hover the cursor pointer to the little cross to close the tab.

Comment: Why would something bad happen if you uninstalled an application.  **Just uninstall the application.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just renamed c:\Program Files\ASUS\ASUS VivoBook\ASUS VivoBook.exe so the program can't be found.
I stil get the small message that vivobook is initializing, but that is less annoying.

**UPDATE**: If you rename vivokey.exe, then the initializing message also dissapears.

Comment: @MegaRodeon If you have to rename the program executables just to prevent it from running, you might as well uninstall it entirely. The [ASUS VivoBook utility](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS%20VivoBook&p=3&s=588&os=41&hashedid=n/a) is not strictly required (in fact, it's only needed to make the Vivo key work) and can be always reinstalled later on.

Comment: true, but now I can still run it manually if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

The sad thing is: This bloatware may be in charge of handling all touch capabilities of the computer as well any other number of things.  Your best bet is to go to ASUS's support page and make sure this application is downloadable.  If 'yes' then download it.  Then uninstall the program from your computer.  Do problems occur?  Is functionality impaired? If 'yes' then re-install the program that you downloaded earlier and write to ASUS support to see if certain portions of the program can be, at very least, disabled.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll see what it would do after uninstalling the app.

Comment: There was a question above:  "Why would something bad happen...?"  Because it is a notebook computer and sometimes the proprietary software is necessary for touch capabilities. I thought I had made this clear.  Also, you should not just "uninstall" unless you have made proper arrangements for re-installing if necessary.